# How to I respond to a user pressing a UISegment?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, events, uisegmentedcontrol

How to I respond to a user pressing a UISegment? Is there a delegate, or must I programmatically (or Interface Builder), attach the selectors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UISegmentedControl subclasses UIControl and sends out the control event `UIControlEventValueChanged` whenever the selected segment changes. You can add a target/action pair for this event in code, or you can do it with the normal control-click-and-drag in IB.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer to do it in code you can use:

```
[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(didSelectIndex:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

And this is then the method that would be called

```
- (void) didSelectIndex: (id) sender
{
    NSLog(@"%@",[(UISegmentedControl *)sender titleForSegmentAtIndex:[(UISegmentedControl *)sender selectedSegmentIndex]]); //replace this with your code
}
```

If you prefer to use IB, right click on your UISegmentedControl select `Value Changed`and then attach it to the desired method in your first responder.